# What algorithms are available to identify similarity scores between two records?

Tags: machine-learning, python, algorithms

I have data that looks like this:

```
priority    task         area 
1           clean room   living room
2           clean room   living room
2           water plants bedroom
```

I want to identify records with a priority of 2 that should be a priority of 1 based on similarity between the priority 2 task and each priority 1 task.

The result data would look like this:

```
priority    task         area         propensity_for_priority_1
1           clean room   living room  1
2           clean room   bedroom      .5
2           water plants bedroom      0
```

String similarity does not need to be performed (i.e. living room and bedroom are mutually exclusive). Is there a matching algorithm that can be used to compare various fields and result in one `propensity_for_priority_1` score for each record?

Comment: Do you have a list of tasks labelled as priority 2 that you know should be priority 1? And/or should not be priority 1?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compare how match the records are with those priority 1 records. And since you have only two field, "task" and "area", so I guess the propensity_for_priority_1 will be one of the values in {0, .5, 1}?

Answer (score 0):

2 Approaches.

a) [Siamese networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_neural_network), let the net tell you whats similiar and what lies together.

b) just perform multiclassification if the data permits, I dont know all the details but it looks like it.

Comment: yep - I'm using a random forest right now that's working pretty well. however, I was wondering if there are methods that are a notch below actual modeling that would be equally as effective.